# Customize x and y labels in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have two lists `xs` and `ys` of equal length that I use to draw a scatter plot:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(50)]
ys = [random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(50)]

plt.scatter(xs,ys)
```

However, I don't want the standard axis labels but rather labels inferred from, e.g. the following dictionaries:

```
x_labels = { 40 : "First", 52 : "Second", 73: "Third" , 99: "Forth" }
y_labels = { 10 : "FIRST", 80 : "SECOND" }
```

So what I'm trying to do is to have a scatter plot with the label "First" at x = 40, "Second" at x = 73 and so on, as well as "FIRST" at y = 10 and "SECOND" at y = 80. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! The only drawback: The x and y values of the point I'm hovering over with the mouse are no longer shown in the bottom right corner once I add the customized x-ticks. Is there a way to disable this behaviour? The x and y are still valid and useful despite the new labels. Or, to take it one step further, can I use customized values or map a dictionary of strings onto the x and y values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the tick labels at the desired position, you can use:

```py
plt.xticks(list(x_labels.keys()), x_labels.values())
plt.yticks(list(y_labels.keys()), y_labels.values())
```

As you noted, this has as consequence that the coordinates aren't displayed any more in the status bar.

A workaround to get the coordinates displayed as well as custom ticks, is using a [custom tick formattter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html). Such a formatter gets two arguments: an `x` value and a `pos`. `pos` is None when displaying the coordinates in the status bar, but is set for the tick labels. So, checking on `pos` not None, the formatter can return the desired label, while otherwise the number formatted as a string can be returned. The tick positions still need to be set via `plt.xticks()`, but not the labels.

Here is an example:

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_x_formatter(x, pos):
    if pos is not None:
        return f"{x_labels_list[pos]}"
    x_r = int(round(x))
    if x_r in x_labels:
        return f"{x:.0f}:{x_labels[x_r]}"
    else:
        return f"{x:.2f}"

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_y_formatter(y, pos):
    if pos is not None:
        return f"{y_labels_list[pos]}"
    y_r = int(round(y))
    if y_r in y_labels:
        return f"{y:.0f}:{y_labels[y_r]}"
    else:
        return f"{y:.2f}"

xs = [random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(50)]
ys = [random.randrange(0,100) for i in range(50)]

plt.scatter(xs,ys)

x_labels = { 40 : "First", 52 : "Second", 73: "Third" , 99: "Forth" }
x_labels_list = list(x_labels.values())
y_labels = { 10 : "FIRST", 80 : "SECOND" }
y_labels_list = list(y_labels.values())
plt.xticks(list(x_labels.keys()))
plt.yticks(list(y_labels.keys()))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_x_formatter)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(major_y_formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: A simple upvote is not enough. Thank you for showing how to get this done!